# how to get java proxy values set in control panel->java->network setting

Tags: java, networking, proxy, jnlp, control-panel

I wanted to know how can I get the values of proxy settings that a user sets for java applications in control panel?

I tried using [How to get proxy settings from system settings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910001/how-to-get-proxy-settings-from-system-settings-in-java) but i got Direct Access as output when i was actually behind proxy.

I know jnlp does it by default but I was using advanced installer(exe) so had to do it programmatically.

Comment: Are you talking about settings in the web browser?  If so, it would help if you mentioned which browser and OS you are using.  If not, what control panel are you talking about?

Comment: Are there any news on this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631075/java-control-panel-proxy-settings-where-are-they-stored