# Java Control Panel Proxy Settings - where are they stored?

Tags: java, batch-file, proxy

I have... a situation. Imagine you have many, many PCs (Windows 7 to 8) that run a Java Application which is started by using a .jnlp. Now finally there has been a version-jump from java 6 to 8 (took way to much time), and suddenly this application wont start any more (can't parse first jnlp, javaws tells me).

To solve this we have to insert the correct proxy-setting inside java-control panel (wasn't necessary with the old version).
So... doing this by hand is a task that most users can't perform (sadly their level of knowledge isn't sufficient), but doing ths by myself at all PCs would take... uh... a really long time.

So we decided to create a little batch-file, that does perform all the stuff necessary (installing latest jre, clearing cache and so on) which just has to be runned once at every users PC. In Theory.

We were able to place all steps necessary in that .bat, **except for setting the proxy at the java control panel**. I wonder if this is possible at all. The javaws arguments don't contain such an argument, and I wasn't able to find a physical storage whatever inside the jre or the java cache.

And I can't use these -dHTTP.xxx.... flags for that .jnlp file I'm afraid, because that java webstart is the one that need to know the correct proxy-settings, not the application.

*So is there a way to change the proxy setting you can access with the java control panel by some command line argument or something like this, enabling myself to complete this "all new" script?*

Greetings, ConfusedMerlin

Comment: Is this any use? http://www.sevenforums.com/software/357828-java-control-panel-network-setting-registry.html

Comment: Oh, it does look promising... i can insert the settings I need to, but as soon as I do open the controlpanel again to verify the change it switches back to the old value (I think I can even see the stuff inserted changing)... close one. Needs more research, but thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java control panel settings are located in `%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties`

to add proxy you can use something like

```
(
 (echo(deployment.proxy.bypass.local=true)
 (echo(deployment.proxy.type=1)
 (echo(deployment.proxy.http.host=10.10.10.10)
 (echo(deployment.proxy.http.port=10)
)>>"%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties"
```

though if there are already set proxy you'll need to replace the data.

Comment: So its in the cache folder after all, its just me being blind. Thanks for your hints, I think I may be able to complete this now.

Comment: @npockmaka These unbalanced parentheses are making my eyes go all funny - even though the syntax is perfectly correct. ;-)

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou - this should not be a correct a syntax ,but cmd parser is strange and buggy.Though this is an old "hack" and [one of the safest ways to echo](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4554#p4554)

Comment: @npocmaka cmd is indeed very quirky, but I wouldn't say buggy. It would be buggy if its surprising features weren't documented. But they are documented. Just not by Microsoft ;-)