# retrieving default values defined in Java net.properties file

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy, network-programming, environment-variables

If I understand [Java Networking and Proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) correctly, the `jre/lib/net.properties` file contains default values that are populated into the system properties at runtime. My `net.properties` file contains the following, among other things:

```
http.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1]
```

But when I run my Java application inside Eclipse 4.5, `System.getProperty("http.nonProxyHosts")` returns `null`. *I have not defined or overridden this value anywhere within my application.*

How am I able to retrieve the value of `http.nonProxyHosts` defined in `jre/lib/net.properties` at runtime?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Summary of conclusions

1. The file `${java.home}/lib/net.properties` does not get loaded into the [System Properties (`System::getProperties`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--).
2. Setting the proxy manually either through `System.setProperty`, or setting at the command line, for example using `-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy` syntax, will override the the defined property, but also any `java.net.useSystemProxies` setting even if set to `true`.
3. You can access the `net.properties` file by loading it manually as properties using [`Properties::load`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-). The exact location is in the Java Home directory, which can be retrieved using the [`java.home`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--) System Property, within the `lib` subdirectory.
4. On a windows desktop, when used in combination with `java.net.useSystemProxies=true`, you set the proxy used from the control panel, under 'Internet Properties'. From those settings you will need to click on the 'LAN settings' button.
5. An applet has an additional level of settings, see [Proxy Setup](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/proxy_setup.xml) in the Java documentation.

## Research

I have replicated your example in my environment, using netBeans actually, with this simple example:

```
public class Play {
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("http.nonProxyHosts"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies"));
 }
}
```

I print the `java.home` system property to make sure I am editing the correct `jre/lib/net.properties`.

however the two properties `http.nonProxyHosts` and `java.net.useSystemProxies` print as null, while I can clearly see that both values are set in the `net.properties` file:

```
java.net.useSystemProxies=false
http.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1]
```

Actually the documentation is a little unclear, but it seems that proxy configuration can be done in one of several ways:

1. `jre/lib/net.properties` as the default
2. From your System's internet settings (Control Panel etc) when `java.net.useSystemProxies` is set to true.
3. From the Java Configuration, as set in your Java Control panel, and when ran as an Applet, and potentially inherited from your browser settings.
4. `System.properties`

It appears to me that this is a cusom feature of the java.net api's, and will read the net.properties only in case the system properties are not set explicitly. I suspect that does *not* mean that the `net.properties` file is used to set system properties, but are only read by the java.net api's themselves.

Note also this text within the default installed `net.properties` file:

> This file may contain default values for the networking system
>   properties. These values are only used when the system properties are
>   not specified on the command line or set programatically.

It only says that these values will be *used*, nothing specific about setting the system properties themselves.

[UPDATE]

With a small example, I was able to prove that out

```
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.ProxySelector;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

public class Play {
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("http.proxyHost"));
    ProxySelector ps = ProxySelector.getDefault();
    List<Proxy> proxies = ps.select(URI.create("http://www.yahoo.com"));
    System.out.println("HTTP Proxies");
    for (Proxy p:proxies) {
      System.out.append(p.toString()).append("\n");
    }
 }
}
```

You can see that the `http.proxyHost` prints as null, while with the default `net.properties`, the proxy for `"http://www.yahoo.com"` prints as `DIRECT`. `DIRECT` means no proxy. This is because in the `net.properties file,`http.proxyHost` is undefined.

Now I modify the `net.properties` file as follows (un-commenting and modifying the existing entry):

```
http.proxyHost=this.is.a.test.net
```

Now when I run the same code, I get following output:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre
null
HTTP Proxies
HTTP @ this.is.a.test.net:80
```

The System Property is still null, however the same setting from the `net.properties` file did take effect.

Some other observations:

1. When setting the system property explicitly as follows: `System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "other.net");` right before doing the `ProxySelector::select`, will override the value in `net.properties`.
2. Overriding using the system properties will *only* affect the exact same system property. That is, if you only override `http.proxyHost`, it will still inherit `http.proxyPort` if set in `net.properties`.
3. If anywhere, either in the `net.properties` file, or by explicitly setting the system property in code, I set `http.proxyHost` explicitly, this will always override the System default even when `java.net.useSystemProxies` is set to true. `java.net.useSystemProxies=true` only works when the proxy is not explicitly set, and will be otherwise ignored (I have tested and verified this).

[Update 2]

If your ultimate goal is just to access the content of the net.properties file, you can try something as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Play {
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.home"), "lib", "net.properties");

    try (Reader r = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
      props.load(r);
      System.out.println("props loaded!");
    } catch (IOException x) {
      System.err.println("props failed loading!");
      x.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    // Now you have access to all the net.properties!
    System.out.println(props.getProperty("http.proxyHost"));
 }
}
```

You figure out security and privileges!

Comment: Thanks for going to all this work to investigate. Nice job. I think your conclusion is, " I suspect that does not mean that the net.properties file is used to set system properties, but are only read by the java.net api's themselves." That's a reasonable conclusion but it's sort of hidden in the middle of all the text. Just a little helpful feedback: you might want to put a summary introduction line at the beginning in the future to make your conclusion pop out. Thanks again!

Comment: So... do you have a way for one to access the values from `net.properties`? (That was the actual question, although your research was really helpful.)

Comment: @GarretWilson Just read the file as properties (see Update 2). Thanks for the feedback also, maybe I should consider a cleanup edit.

Comment: Ignore my earlier (erased here) comment about finding the file --- I just saw you updated the answer. Thanks for the comprehensive response!

Comment: @GarretWilson Locating in a cross platform fashion is already taken care off in the example. But why not provide your own properties file as part of your app deployment, and have that override all the defaults?